# Mongo db not equal to query not working

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to select all different from "overview" in a mongodb collection. I use the query below but it does not work...

```
hist = db.find({'type':{$ne:'overview'}})
```

If I try without the $ne it works...

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Thanks!

**Update**

Just fixed... had to quote the "$ne"

Comment: Missing colon? `:`. I've never used mongodb, but googling the syntax for `$ne`showed me examples with that syntax.

Comment: sorry, the colon was missing here but not on the code...

Comment: And that why you should _always_ copy-paste. Make it reproducable. Also, your new edit has the colon within the string, that's still wrong.

Comment: you are right... just fixed

Comment: So, your code is failing with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotation marks around `$ne` since pymongo uses dicts as parameters. It can't interpret `{ $ne : 'overview' }` since `$ne` isn't a variable. Long story short, try this:

```
hist = db.find({'type':{'$ne':'overview'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're colon for $ne is inside the quotes, change to:

```
hist = db.find({'type':{$ne:'overview'}})
```

Comment: its like this and I keep getting syntax error everytime I put $ne or $all in a query...

Comment: Ahh, ok. One more thing though, i don't believe you need quotations around type, since you are not searching on a sub-document of type. try removing the single quotes.